# Can't disable javascript with IE developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer, web-development

I want to disable JavaScript with IE developer tools. Under Disable I have the option Script but it's greyed out and I can't select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox you need to uncheck:

[image]

Restart IE and check if you can disable scripts now, it should be.